# Apache2 gives me an internal 500 error while trying to force HTTPS for the client using .htaccess files when using a self-signed certificate

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl-certificate

I have an Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS running Apache2 web server. As what different tutorials explain, I have created a private certificate key file and also a `.crt` Certificate file using the following command:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/subdomain.hostname.net/ssl.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/subdomain.hostname.net/ssl.crt
```

But the problem is that when I use an `.htaccess` file in the document root to force HTTPS redirect for the client, it gives me an internal 500 error:

Here's the virtual host config file I've set up:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@subdomain.hostname.net
    ServerName subdomain.hostname.net

    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/subdomain.hostname.net

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin admin@subdomain.hostname.net
            ServerName subdomain.hostname.net

            DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/subdomain.hostname.net

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/subdomain.hostname.net/ssl.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/subdomain.hostname.net/ssl.key

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

            BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A 500 error in a web browser usually has a more detailed explanation in the server error logs.

Did you check the error logs in `/var/log/apache2/`?

You can probably clearly see the 500 error cause in one of the error logs.

Get on that server and just run this command:

```
ls -latr /var/log/apache2/
```

That will list all the files in reverse update order and the most recently updated file will be at the bottom of the list. I like to do this kind of listing in reverse since the directory can contain tons of files and listing it in reverse order will allow the most recently modified files to be at the bottom of this list.

I bet it will be an error log file that has that 500 in it with a more specific explanation of what is happening will be there.

FWIW, in my experience in cases like this — server worked, small change made, nothing works — it is typically a typo in a config or in a related `.htaccess` file in the website’s codebase.